# Can I use key bindings in Sublime Text to open remote files?

Tags: sftp, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

Every time I start a new programming session I have to open many “remote” files.

I was hoping to find a way to use key bindings to open those files. However, if this is possible I can't seem to find the proper way to do so.

Current I have a keybinding to popup the SFTP server, but then I still have to scroll to the correct server, and scroll through files, select one, hit edit, and repeat for another 3 - 4 files. It's a bit tedious. Currently I have:

```
[ { "keys": ["f11"], "command": "sftp_browse_server" }]
```

But would love to expand it to something like this, if possible :

```
[{
    "keys": ["shift+f11"],
    "command": "open",
    "args": {"file":"http://x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/helloWorld.pl"}
}
]
```

Comment: How do you typically open these remote files?

Comment: @MattDMo I put more info in the OP